# Iterating over an Array of Arrays and returning the inner arrays with duplicate id's

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript, and have been looking for an answer to this but can't seem to find a similar question on stackoverflow. I am trying to iterate over an array of arrays and only return the arrays that have duplicate id's. I can't use lodash or jQuery, just plain vanilla JS. So given the array below:

```
iceCreamArray =  [ 
  [1, Chocolate],
  [1, Vanilla],
  [2, Chocolate],
  [3, Vanilla],
  [4, Chocolate],
  [4, Vanilla],
  [5, Vanilla]
]
```

Would return:

```
resultArray = [ 
  [1, Chocolate],
  [1, Vanilla],
  [4, Chocolate],
  [4, Vanilla],
]
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
iceCreamArray.forEach(function(flavor) {
  if (flavor[0] === flavor[0].next){
     resultArray.push(flavor)
  }

})
```

Comment: what happens to `[2, 'Chocolate']`? please add the building rule of the new array.

Comment: So it removes 2, 3, and 5 because there isn't another array with the id 2, 3, or 5. The only repeats are 1 and 4.

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to already be pre-sorted by ID? What you you have two duplicate records (ie ids and flavors are both the same)?

Comment: The array isn't necessarily pre-sorted, but the id will always be in the zero-index of it's array. There will also never be any duplicate record. I essentially just need something to map over the entire array, look at each id, if that id matches another arrays id, then pull that array out and push it into the result array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var iceCreamArray = [ 
    [1, "Chocolate"],
    [1, "Vanilla"],
    [2, "Chocolate"],
    [3, "Vanilla"],
    [4, "Chocolate"],
    [4, "Vanilla"],
    [5, "Vanilla"]
]

// count ids
var id_counts = {};
iceCreamArray.forEach(function(flavor) {
    var id;
    id = flavor[0];
    if (typeof id_counts[id] === "undefined") {
        id_counts[id] = 0;
    }
    id_counts[id] += 1;
});

// filter records for ids that occur more than once
console.log(iceCreamArray.filter(function(flavor) {
    return id_counts[flavor[0]] > 1;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the occurence of the same `id` and filter then the array with the count.

```js
var iceCreamArray = [[1, 'Chocolate'], [1, 'Vanilla'], [2, 'Chocolate'], [3, 'Vanilla'], [4, 'Chocolate'], [4, 'Vanilla'], [5, 'Vanilla']],
    count = Object.create(null),
    result;

iceCreamArray.forEach(([id]) => count[id] = (count[id] || 0) + 1);
result = iceCreamArray.filter(([id]) => count[id] !== 1);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```